# connect laravel to telnet without putty

Tags: telnet, laravel-10

I tried to connect Telnet with Laravel without the help of PuTTY, then tried many available packages but did not succeed. Has anyone ever tried and succeeded, especially for the most recent versions of PHP and Laravel. I really need it

i try some package, and isnt work